# How to get the error fields in form panel using ext js2.3?

Tags: extjs, formpanel

How to get the error fields from the form panel using ext js2.3.
There is nothing called getFields in this version to use. So is there any alternate to get the fields?

Comment: Will getValues() on the form help you in anyway here? So...myFormPanel.getForm().getValues()

Comment: I had used clientvalidation(this,bool) to notify if form is valid or not rather than getting values for each field